# Can PS4 play with PS3

Tags: ps3, ps4, grand-theft-auto-online

I recently got a PS4 and I was wondering if I could play games like GTA:V with my PS3 friends? I'm thinking that you can't but wanted to confirm. I tried playing with them but it says that they aren't playing GTA:V.

Answer (score 0):

**No to GTA V.**

There is no official statement about this, but Rockstar never announced to be working on any form of crossplay feature for GTA V afaik.

**Other games**

However, there are games that do offer online crossplay between the PS3 and the PS4, see [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_games_that_support_cross-platform_play).